# Collision detection is not returning inside limits

Tags: javascript

Full code [here](https://github.com/3noki/udacity_front_end_web_developer/tree/master/project_3_frogger_style_arcade_game)

I am trying to setup the functions to detect collisions and for now just log to the console. This is the section for checkCollision function;

```
Player.prototype.update = function(dt) {
  checkCollision(this.leftLimit, this.rightLimit);
  this.leftLimit = this.x - 40.5;
  this.rightLimit = this.x + 40.5;
}

function checkCollision(playerl,playerr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var thisEnemy = allEnemies[i];
      if (thisEnemy.leftlimit > playerl && thisEnemy.rightLimit < playerr) {console.log("1")}
      else {console.log('else')}
    }
}
```

**Question**

The character is never registering as colliding with the enemy, why is this not working?

**Testing/Debugging**

I know this function is working as consoles logging else, I've also put logging in other locations and when in the Enemy.prototype.update function, console was showing values like 202.000000093, since the for..else function is using < or >, not absolute values, that should be fine, but still nothing is matching inside the player left and right limits.  I also tried changing the Enemy limits to be smaller, +/- 40.5, incase the enemy was too wide to fit inside the player limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a better if statement to check if there's a collision;

```
 if (
    thisEnemy.leftLimit < player.rightLimit &&
    thisEnemy.rightLimit > player.leftLimit &&
    thisEnemy.upperLimit > player.lowerLimit &&
    thisEnemy.lowerLimit < player.upperLimit) {
    console.log("collision");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

player.leftLimit and player.rightLimit are undefined when checkCollision method is first running